# Problems with WebApplication after Host Header name is given

Tags: site-collection, central-administration, site, web-application, host-header

I have created a Web App with Host Header and created a Site collection in it. There was no error message or any problems pertaining while creating web app or site collection but problem comes when I am trying to access the Web App.
Please help me with this!!! Some of my frnd suggested me to configure alternate access mapping but I have no Idea what has to be mapped.. Please answer on step by step basis

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the error/behavior? Did you set any name resolution (hosts file or DNS entry) that resolve the host name to the IP of the server ?

Comment: I assume there is a DNS record in place for your host header pointing to the correct web server? A hosts file entry would also do for local testing. Do you get any error message?

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Please edit  your post and add details as requested by the community. It will be  closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question  flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Is this SharePoint 2010 or MOSS? When you say you have a problem accessing the site - what does that mean? a 404? blank page? constant authentication? what is the issue?

You need to check in Central admin for alternate access mappings (where this is, depends on 2010 or 2007), this sets up the valid URLs your web application can be accessed on. Also double check in IIS that the host header is present on the new site.

Need more detail to diagnose this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use host headers you need to check the Loopback adapter settings for your server:

Instructions can be found here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861